# How to get the column types of a dataframe into a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm trying to pull the column types into a list using:

```
df.dtypes.tolist()
```

However this is giving the output as `[dtype('int64'),dtype('float64'), ......` instead of `['int64','float64'.......`

Comment: To clarify, you want the `dtypes` as a list of strings? (also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to format code and edit your question).

Comment: Thanks @Bill for helping with the formatting. And yes i want the dtypes as a list of strings

Comment: `df.dtypes` results in a series object, which you can immediately type cast to string in a vectorized manner, with `.astype(str)`. Then `tolist()` can get you the list you need. I have added this in an answer below, as it maybe more efficient then iterating directly OR using an apply function to typecast.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
[str(d) for d in df.dtypes]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
>>> df.dtypes.apply(str).tolist()
['object', 'float64', 'object']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Series.astype(str)` rather than an `pd.Series.apply(str)`, or direct iteration with `for` loops, as it should be more efficient since it's vectorized.

```
df.dtypes.astype(str).tolist()
```

```
['int64','float64','int64']
```